# View greyscale RAW image file in C++ using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, grayscale

I have a a raw image file which contains image data from the 5th byte onwards. 
Each byte in the file represents a 8 bit greyscale pixel intensity.
I have been able to store the binary data of the image in a 2-D unsigned char array.

Can anyone tell me how to use the array or the file to display the image in openCV?

Right now I am using this code :

```
void openRaw() {
    cv::Mat img(numRows,numCols,CV_8U,&(image[0][0]);
    //img.t();
    cv::imshow("img",img);  
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

But its displaying a wrong image.

I also tried using the IplImage method, but I am not sure how to pass the pointer to the source image there.

Could anyone provide me with some code for this?

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: If image data start as byte 5 then I guess it is not all that raw. Do the previous bytes contain the resolution? It would be a little hard to guess, unless it is a perfect square...

Answer (score 1):

"I have been able to store the binary data of the image in a 2-D unsigned char array."

that's your problem here.

opencv stores the pixel data in consecutive uchar*, so it expects the same from you.

your 2d array is most likely an array of pointers, it's not the same.

so: instead of the 2d array, make a 1d :

```
uchar *data = new uchar[rows * cols];
```

you can access single pixels there like :

```
uchar pixel = data[y*cols+x];
```

and then pass the data pointer into your cv::Mat :

```
cv::Mat img( rows, cols, CV_8U, data );
```

oh, and please DON'T use IplImages ( aka the 1.0 api ) any more, avoid at all cost!

Comment: thanks! this worked like a charm! I'd like to ask one thing though, can we perform all the arithmetic operations on uchar like we can do on unsigned char?